# Allow portions of a website to be embedded into other websites and different domains

Tags: html, iframe, embedding

I've a website with some graphs and I'd like that some of them could be embedded into other web-sites, that can be in **different domains**.

basically the graphs are unique and have an id, ***example***:

```
...
<HTML>
...
<div id ="group1" name="G1" style="width: 900px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto">
    <div id="graph_1" style="width: 400px; height: 300px; float: left"> </div>
    <div id="graph_2" style="width: 400px; height: 300px; float: left"></div>
</div>

<div id ="group2" name="G2" style="width: 900px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto">
    <div id="graph_3" style="width: 400px; height: 300px; float: left"> </div>
    <div id="graph_4" style="width: 400px; height: 300px; float: left"></div>
</div>

....
</HTML>
```

In another website, could be different Domain

I'd like that other developers could easily add something in a simple way like using an ***iframe*** that could just grab a certain part of my web-page. ***example***:

```
 ...
      <iframe src="http://www.myWebAddress/page.html/#graph_1"  -->
        scrolling="no" frameborder="no" width="400" height="300">
     </iframe>
...
```

But this is not working, it includes the whole page!
What changes can I do in the source (my page) that would make this possible?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible, only if a new unique page is created which contains the graph alone. Then use it inside a iframe.

```
<iframe src="http://www.myWebAddress/page.html?showonly=graph_1"
  scrolling="no" frameborder="no" width="400" height="300">
</iframe>
```

read here, how to create a good widget in js http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/

or the new edge web components https://hacks.mozilla.org/category/web-components/